# Java renameTo Files Showed 0 File Size then were gone...Windows still holds the space though

Tags: java, windows, file

So I have been making a program in Java to organize all my files. I am starting with movie files since that is what I have the most of, but I plan on being able to checkBox all file types eventually.

Anyway, I had `renameTo` working fine when moving all files to a new folder. Next step was trying to alphabetize the files. I got this working fine as well, but obviously I needed to be able to remove articles(i.e. "the", "a", "an") in order to properly alphabetize. I was able to do this in my ArrayList pretty easily, and then decided to actually rename the files.

I did a renameTo in order to rename the file the same filename minus the articles. I used:

```
  File newb = new File(folder+""+filelist[i].getName().substring(4));
  if(filelist[i].renameTo(newb)){}
  else{
      System.out.println("FAILED");
  }
```

Where folder is obviously the folder location the file is in and it is a substring of the original string minus 4 characters at the beginning for the word "The_" or "The."

It then attempts to rename the file from within the same folder to itself minus the substring.

The result of this code is the file disappearing and file size being listed as 0 when calling the length() of that file. The file is not findable in Windows Explorer, BUT there is no extra space on my HDD!

Now to the questions:

1. What is wrong with this? Should I be putting a temp file into another folder or something?
2. Is there a way to release the files from Windows so they are not forever clogging up space on my HDD?
3. Anything else you need to know? Want to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on, but constructing file names by appending strings can cause problems. (In particular, if `folder` doesn't end with the path separator character, you might find your moved files in the parent folder. That would explain why the files disappeared without freeing any disk space. So instead of renaming, say, `C:\movies\The_Sting.avi` to `C:\movies\Sting.avi`, it ended up as `C:\moviesSting.avi`.)

Try this instead:

```
File parent = filelist[i].getParentFile();

String newName = filelist[i].getName().substring(4);
if (!filelist[i].renameTo(new File(parent, newName)) {
    System.out.println("FAILED");
}
```

Obviously, if all the files in `filelist` are from the same folder, then you only have to assign to `parent` once (before you start looping).

Comment: +1 for using the appropriate constructor rather than concatenating with the file separator as I see it done so often.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. You were exactly right. The renamed files were in the parent folder! I did not even think to look there since the original move function worked correctly.  And thank you for your example. This helps me to learn the features of file that I did not know and to better my code :) I am writing this as a learning tool of Java. I am looking to get a java programming job and need to learn learn learn! Although not looking in the parent folder was a stupid mistake, I am glad I asked now!